# Problem detecting USB in 12.04 x64, works on Xubuntu 13.04 64x and windows

Tags: usb, mount

I am banging my head against the wall on this one.

I have a SanDisk Extreme USB 3.0 64GB thumb drive that used to work on my box running 12.04 64bit, but now that box will not detect it in any way I can determine.  I have tried it in several of the USB ports to no avail.

It will detect and mount a other thumb drives, I have two others that work with no issues, a Patriot Memory 32GB drive, and an IronKey.

The SanDisk that does not get detected on the box running 12.04 64bit does get detected and mounted without issue on both my windows laptop and a box I have running Xubuntu 13.04.

With the drive plugged in lsusb returned this:

[image]

When I run dmesg I do not see any info related to this drive.

This might be unrelated, but about the time my system quite seeing this thumb drive, it also started having issues mounting my iphone, I get the "Unhandled Lockdown error (-12)" when I try.

If there is any more information needed to help me on this please let me know.  Thanks to Danatela and Tarula for your replies.

Any thoughts?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information. Especially, add the output of `lsusb` command having USB thumb plugged in.

Comment: Did you tried using any other pen drive, is other pen drive detected or is it not detected as well?

Comment: Any ideas Danatela?  Tarun?